# Sharing a VPN connection using Internet Sharing (via Airport)

Tags: macos, wifi, vpn, internet-sharing

Internet Sharing from my MacBook Pro (10.6.6) to other WiFi devices works fine.

But the moment I turn on the VPN connection (PPTP) on the Mac (which I would also like to share), the other devices cannot access anything anymore (everything works fine on the Mac itself).

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS-X treats a VPN connection as a totally separate connection from the device (airport, ethernet) it is transported on.  So when you turned on your VPN, your airport or ethernet *connection* was no longer active.

If you want to share the VPN connection, you have to set up sharing for it the same way you did for your primary, non-VPN connection.  They behave totally separately, for sharing purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Linking to rodrigo.sharpcube.com is appalling. I lost hours of my life following it. It's a totally unnecessary wild goose chase into IPFW. Please avoid. The first answer from JRobert is accurate. Here is a [more detailed step by step with images](http://foliovision.com/2014/02/share-ethernet-osx).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you follow the excellent blogpost by Rodrigo at http://rodrigo.sharpcube.com/2010/06/20/using-and-sharing-a-vpn-connection-on-your-mac/

Worked for me.

Comment: +1 I'll give that a try. Those manual settings for `ipfw` do not persist anywhere, right? (I don't want to break anything). Do I need to reboot to flush them out again, or just a VPN disconnect?

Comment: in order to "flush" just issue a: ipfw -q flush, no need to reboot.

Comment: Martin is correct, no need to reboot. If you're obsessive compulsive like me, on OS X 10.6.x you can go to System Preferences->Security->Firewall (rightmost tab) and turn it off then on. You'll may be prompted for Administrator password.

Comment: Alas, this post by Rodrigo simply does not work. After losing hours trying to make it work, I painstakingly built a [working shared VPN connection](http://foliovision.com/2014/02/share-ethernet-osx) and documented it..

Answer (score 0):

To share a VPN connection on 10.7, using [WaterRoof](http://www.hanynet.com/waterroof/), follow [these directions](http://forum.gizmolord.com/macos/how-to-share-vpn-over-wifi-for-mac-os-x/).

To share a VPN on 10.8 and above, do the same thing with [IceFloor](http://www.hanynet.com/icefloor/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here are [instructions for sharing your ExpressVPN connection on Mac OS X using Internet Sharing](https://www.expressvpn.com/support/vpn-setup/share-vpn-connection-mac) (uses L2TP.)