# Enable internet sharing via iPhone USB

Tags: macos, iphone

This is not a duplicate of the questions posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/sharing-internet-from-macbook-to-iphone)  and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52487/internet-sharing-on-mac-via-lan)

It is a duplicate of the question posted [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-access-to-iphone-via-usb) however there is no answer to that question and one of the commenters is wrong about the direction of sharing. I am posting this again to hopefully get a solution for this.

I have enabled internet sharing in OSX via settings -> sharing then clicking on internet sharing. I have tried this using wifi which works just fine, however I am no longer allowed to create a wifi network because security.

My new plan is to use the iPhone USB option to share my Mac's ethernet connection with my iPhone. The setup seems simple and I have selected "Share your connection from: Ethernet" "To computers using: iPhone USB". I don't currently have a connection to the internet. Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, won't work. The iPhone needs a Wireless network to connect to the internet.

If you aren't connected to a Wifi network and you disabled cellular data, you'll get a popup saying you need a connection.

Comment: What does share "To computers using: iPhone USB" mean?

Comment: My guess : OSX recognizes the iPhone a USB network device (sharing internet iPhone -> Mac works), but the iPhone just want wireless connection.

Comment: As of Sept 2019 it is now possible to do so, check Ring O answer.

Answer (score 4):

The question is old but it seems it is now possible to share a Mac Internet connection from the ethernet port, with an iPhone connected to the Mac via a USB ↔ lightning cable,

- Ensure the Mac Internet is working properly via the (thunderbolt adapter) ethernet port
- Connect the iPhone (iPad) via the USB ↔ lightning cable
- Unlock the iPhone ; if its asks for "Trust this computer?", tap "Trust"
- Go to the Mac <kbd>System Preferences</kbd> <kbd>Sharing</kbd> [ uncheck "Internet sharing" if it is checked in order to allow changes to "To computers using:" ]
- Choose "Share your connection from:" either "Ethernet" or "Thunderbolt ethernet"
- Check the "To computers using:" "iPhone USB" box then check the "Internet sharing" service.

The iPhone should now be able to use Internet from the Mac.

If you want to be sure the iPhone is really using the Mac connection, switch off "Wifi" and "Cellular data".

[ *achieved on iOS 10.3.2, MacOS Sierra 10.12.5* ]

Comment: It's 2019, this doesn't work for me...
Only "iPad USB" can be choosen, and still no internet in iPhone...
iOS 12.2, macOS 10.14.4

Comment: @RichardFu Sorry to hear that, and thanks for reminding the year. Did you follow the procedure exactly? It's quite complicated.

Comment: Yes I did, I even try connect my iPhone with Bluetooth, still no internet.... anyway thx for the reply....