# Cannot share internet from MacBook to iPhone via usb cable; option not available

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, network, usb, internet-sharing

This is not a duplicate question asked [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/can-i-share-my-imacs-internet-to-iphone-or-ipad-over-usb) or [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104985/enable-internet-sharing-via-iphone-usb).

I cannot tether internet to my iPhone from my MacBook Pro using a USB cable; the option to do so is simply not available (see screenshot). The device I am using as the gateway to the internet is my MacBook, connected to the internet via ethernet. I do not want to use Bluetooth or wifi to share internet.
I can access my iPhone normally from finder (i.e. my MacBook recognizes the device). My previous MacBook had an `iPhone USB` option in the `To computers using:` list which my current MacBook lacks.

My devices:

- MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), macOS Catalina, Version 10.15.4
- iPhone 7 iOS 13.3.1

[image]

Comment: This is a bit unclear - which device are you trying to use as the gateway to the Internet, the MacBook or the iPhone?  In other words, which one is connected to the Internet that you want to share?

Comment: @Allan, the MacBook is the gateway to the internet. I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MacOS Catalina, the internet sharing settings for iOS devices are located under the content Caching section.
[image]

I've verified that it works with MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 on a 2018 Macbook Pro and an iPhone 7 Plus running iOS 13.4.1

The network is sharing wifi from my macbook, with the iPhone's cellular, wifi and bluetooth disabled. Safari was able to load up multiple pages.

*note it may take a few minutes to set the cache up before pages load on your iPhone

Also note that when content caching is on, the internet sharing service is disabled as is controlled by content caching

To read more from apple, [view their guide](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl3b6c3720/mac)

Comment: It doesn't seem intuitive to me to that sharing internet connection is not placed in "internet sharing", or I must be missing something... Thanks for that! Works fine now

Comment: I believe it was moved to content caching after High Sierra as most users were utilising the feature for enterprise setup of multiple devices. For more info on how the caching itself works an interesting read is available here: https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchl9388ba1b/10.15/mac/10.15

Answer (score 0):

On Catalina 10.15.06 the above procedure does not work.

After enabling Content Caching and selecting internet connection, my iPad Pro 4th generation cannot use the connection.

Is there anything I should do on the iPad side?

EDIT: The Macbook Pro is connected through wifi, and I am trying to use internet on the ipad via the usb-c cable.