# Internet sharing from MacBook to iPad Pro via USB cable (Tethered caching) not working on Catalina 10.15.6

Tags: ipad, wifi, catalina, usb, tethering

I would like to share the internet connection on my MacBook Pro (a Wi-Fi connection) with my iPad Pro 4th generation via USB-C cable. The MacBook Pro is running Catalina 10.15.6. My Mac has far superior Wi-Fi reception than my iPad for unknown reasons.

I followed the instructions in [Cannot share internet from MacBook to iPhone via USB cable; option not available](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388367/cannot-share-internet-from-macbook-to-iphone-via-usb-cable-option-not-available):

**System Preferences** > **Content Sharing** > Switch ON and check **Internet connection**.

However, nothing happens on the iPad. I can't load any page.

Is there anything I should do on the iPad-side before setting up the tethering again?

Answer (score 1):

I just realized that the iPad was not showing in the Finder. I rebooted the iPad, now it shows in the finder and the connection started working.

I suppose then that it is/was a problem with the connection between the two devices, rather then the tethering itself. I will monitor the behaviour in the next days.

Answer (score -1):

Is that how it looks for you?

[image]

You can choose something else instead of WiFi. At the moment your WiFi connection from the Mac goes through the USB port.

Please note, however, that you do not select the same network interface for "Share connection" and for "With computers via:" otherwise you will receive the message:

> If you activate this connection, your Internet provider can disconnect
> your connection to prevent network disruption.
>
> If you z. For example, if you are using a cable modem, you may
> inadvertently change the network settings of your Internet provider
> and violate the license agreement.