# How can I share my mac's internet connection while it's connected to a VPN?

Tags: macos, network, vpn, internet-sharing

I have a mac running macOS 10.14.6 that's connected to Wi-Fi. I want to share its internet connection to some other systems connected to my mac's ethernet port via an ethernet switch.

If I turn on Internet Sharing and share from Wi-Fi to ethernet, it works fine. But my mac is also usually connected to a VPN (in this case using Viscosity, an OpenVPN client). So long as the VPN is connected, internet sharing stops working. The other systems connected via ethernet receive an IP address via DHCP, but no traffic can get out of the local network created by my mac. This is illustrated by `traceroute` that fails like so:

```
traceroute to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  0.353 ms  0.302 ms  0.290 ms
 2  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  0.293 ms !H  0.259 ms !H  0.262 ms !H
```

Is there any way to get internet sharing to work while the mac is connected to the VPN? Preferably the other systems connected to it wouldn't be going through the VPN too, but that's acceptable if there's no other good way to get it to work.

Comment: There’s likely two things going on simultaneously. 1) does your [vpn configuration allow split tunnel](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415649/5472) - if not, you’re stuck. 2) what results do you get when you explicitly [share out the VPN connection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/10382/5472)?

Comment: @bmike macOS doesn't give me the option of sharing the VPN connection. Its BSD-style interface is `utun10` but it's not listed in the Network system preferences, nor is it available in the Sharing system preferences. As for split tunneling, its an OpenVPN client so I can configure it however I want. Maybe I need to make an explicit route for traffic on my mac's local network?

Comment: Wonderful, yes - you may need to map out the network segments and routing. Bummer you don’t get a proper network extension. I never solved this on 10.14 and hope to not need to on 12 and higher with network extensions.